# How to upload files from database on FTP remote server?

Tags: php, database, server, ftp, hosting

I use PHP to upload images from a host into FTP remote server.

I have already stored the names of the files that need to be uploaded to the FTP remote server, stored on the database.

After connecting to DB and a query for select information of images, I passed variables with $_SESSION to another PHP file for upload them on FTP remote server like this:

**conn_auth.php for select target images:**

```
<?php

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/conn_auth/db_conn.php')){
    include __DIR__.'/conn_auth/db_conn.php';
}else{
    die('Connection is Failed ...!');
}

$conn = OpenConn();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where status = 'Active'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_id = $row["id"];
        //search for user_id in userAthentication Table in DB
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM userauthentication where user_id = $user_id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $user_auth = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $user = array(
            'id'=>$row['id'],
            'name'=>$row['name'],
            'family'=>$row['family'],
            'auth_image'=>'',
            'file_name'=>$user_auth["image"],
            'phone'=>$row["phone"]
        );


    $url = "/home/root/app_name_1/uploads/".$user["file_name"];

    
    if(!file_exists($url)){
        $url = "/home/root/app_name_2/uploads/".$user["file_name"];

    }
    $user['auth_image'] = $url;

    session_start();
    $_SESSION["userInfo"] = $user;
    $_SESSION["userAuth"] = $user_auth;

    if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/conn_auth/get_auth.php')){
        include __DIR__.'/conn_auth/get_auth.php';
    }else{
        die("I can't Connect to the Server");
    }

   }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

CloseConn($conn);
```

On this file, I try to connect to FTP remote server and upload images with the ftp_put() method, but it does not work:

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__.'../conn_auth.php';
session_start();
$ftp_server="*.***.***.**";
$ftp_user_name="****";
$ftp_user_pass="**********";
$file = $_SESSION["userInfo"]['auth_image']; //to be uploaded
$folder_name = $_SESSION["userInfo"]['phone'];
$file_name = $_SESSION["userInfo"]["file_name"];
$remote_file = "/HDD/pics/$folder_name";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,21);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_mkdir($conn_id,'auth_pics').ftp_chdir($conn_id,'auth_pics');



if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id,"$folder_name")){
    ftp_chdir($conn_id,$folder_name);

}else{
    echo "I Can't Create Folder For : ".$folder_name;
    die();
}
// upload a file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);

if ($upload) {

    echo "successfully uploaded : $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading...\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: What error messages do you see?

Comment: The ftp_put() method return false and don't upload anything...
I get this error every time the code is executed : "There was a problem while uploading..." @Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly your FTP server doesn't support active mode connections, so you may try to switch to the passive mode using the [ftp_pasv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php), but make sure to do this  after you logged into the server (after ftp_login).

If you face some troubles while using the native API functions, you may want to try out an FTP client library, like [this](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-client), that I've built.

Hope you find this answer useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, Chakir. Finally, my problem was solved with your suggested solution. ♥
@el-amrani-chakir

Comment: That's great, good lock!